# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/com.android.tools/proguard/coroutines.pro' in Unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

I reimport Firebase SDK and build my project, I get the following error: **More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/com.android.tools/proguard/coroutines.pro'**

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
// Android Resolver Dependencies Start
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.2.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/DatabaseDependencies.xml:17
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.3.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/DatabaseDependencies.xml:15
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-app-unity:11.3.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:22
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.1.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AuthDependencies.xml:13
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-unity:11.3.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AuthDependencies.xml:20
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common:20.3.3' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:13
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.2.2' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/DatabaseDependencies.xml:13
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-unity:11.3.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/DatabaseDependencies.xml:22
// Android Resolver Dependencies End
    implementation(name: 'UnityAds', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'UnityAdsAndroidPlugin', ext:'aar')
    implementation project('FirebaseApp.androidlib')
}

// Android Resolver Exclusions Start
android {
  packagingOptions {
      exclude ('/lib/armeabi/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/mips/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/mips64/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/x86/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/x86_64/*' + '*')
      exclude ('META-INF/com.android.tools/proguard/coroutines.pro')
  }
}
// Android Resolver Exclusions End
android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.2'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
        }
        versionCode 1
        versionName '0.9.0'
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-unity.txt'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        ignoreAssetsPattern = "!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        doNotStrip '*/armeabi-v7a/*.so'
        doNotStrip '*/arm64-v8a/*.so'
    }
}
```

I using Unity 2019.4.39f1 and Firebase Realtime Database

I tried, but it didn't solve my problem

```
  packagingOptions {
      exclude ('META-INF/com.android.tools/proguard/coroutines.pro')
  }
```

Comment: So, after another attempt reimort, I noticed an warning: **Unity is only able to load mdb or portable-pdb symbols. [Filename] is using a legacy pdb format**. I just changed the scripting backeng IL2CCP to Mono. It s work to me